# Реализация хранилища данных для андроид клиента

Tags: android, backend

Хочу реализовать сервер для своего андроид приложения. Он будет принимать с него файлы в формате .csv(в перспективе будут ещё видео, поэтому просто записывать в SQL не пойдет), сохранять, и при необходимости показывать на клиентской стороне все хранящиеся там файлы. Ищу фреймворк для реализации этого всего, а именно какой-то аналог баз данных для хранения этого всего. Раньше думал просто об sftp но я не уверен что смогу просматривать на клиенте хранящиеся там файлы.

Comment: Мне кажется Вы не совсем представляете, что хотите получить в итоге и как этого добиться.

Comment: Если Вам нужно простое внешнее файловое хранилище, то почему не возьмете API Google  Drive, Яндекс Диска, DropBox'а или чего бы то ни было еще более специализированного?

Comment: Если Вам нужно что-то более конкретное и этого нет на рынке, то определитесь чего Вы именно хотите получать и где хранить. Как говориться  `мухи отдельно - котлеты отдельно`. Храните информацию о структуре в БД, а файлы на диске(в общем-то можно где угодно). Пусть у Вас будет какой-либо веб-сервис для возврата информации о структуре хранилища и отдельный контроллер для возврата файлов...либо же использовать для последнего любой http-сервер.